# Developing a gem in parallel with another project

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Let's say your working on a product, and you realise that some of the code is general enough to be extracted out to a gem.

So you create a new project, build the gem, publish it to Rubygems, and then reference it in your main project's Gemfile.

Then you discover a small bug with how the gem interacts with your product. Each time your make a fix, building and installing the gem locally can take about 15 seconds. How do you minimise this to have a quick develop/test cycle?

(Also it seems that the locally built gem's version number could contradict with what you've pushed to Rubygems, leading to confusion.)

Any best practice guides on this subject?

Answer (score 3):

bundler doesn't just know how to get gems from rubygems. You could point it at a git repository

```
gem  'mygem', :git => 'git => 'git://github.com/...'
```

or, much more conveniently in this case

```
gem 'mygem', :path => '~/work/mygem'
```

where the path option points to the folder with the gem's source

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that still require building the gem then running Bundler each time though in order to pick up changes?

Comment: Not the last time I did something similar. Try it!